# How to set webcam video as desktop background?

Tags: webcam, desktop-background, elementary

I use a webcam to monitor inbound traffic, etc. for my office and would like to be able to set my desktop background to be a live feed from my webcam on my secondary or both monitors.  How would one go about setting that up on Ubuntu?

One option would also be to set [`Cheese`](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Cheese) as a background app as it works relatively well at the moment, but the background live wallpaper approach would be better.

Comment: Take a look at http://superuser.com/questions/750949/how-can-i-set-the-live-video-feed-from-the-iss-as-my-desktop-background